# Many-To-Many with additional parameters

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

using the default entity creation commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import testSiteBundle yml
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities test --path=src/
```

Can i make additional parameters in many-to-many relation table work with symfony2+doctrine2 ?

Example case:

```
Table Invoice
  - invoice id
Table Product
  - product id
Relation-Table InvoiceProduct
  - invoice id
  - product id
  - product quantity
```

Doctrine by default don't create relation-tables entities, and trying the example above, the "product quantity" is ignored.

what can i do to manage this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In doctrine, that's not a Many-To-Many relation. It's two OneToMany-Relations with an Entity in the middle

```
Entity:Invoice - ManyToOne - Entity:InvoiceProduct - OneToMany - Entity:Product
```

Your additional attributes are just normal fields of the `InvoiceProduct`-Entity.

Comment: is there any way to tell "doctrine:generate:entities" to do that ?

Comment: I wouldn't know of one. I always create my entities manually as classes. You should ask in the forums or google groups about that to be sure.